# Version controlling assets/resources in S3 , and integrating in code

Tags: version-control, resources, amazon-s3

What is the best way to version control resources. Is there a solution on amazon s3 for this.  I have very large mp4, images, pdf files. They are associated with a project that also has some server side code associated with it, with restful apis to download these resources. As a developer I mostly work out of svn, I am not sure that'a a good place to store the resources

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amazon S3 has native versioning support:

http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2010/02/08/versioning-feature-for-amazon-s3-now-available/